# How to create tags for a text automatically with PHP?

Tags: php, bots

I want to create tags for my content automatically. There would be a constant tag list and the bot should create tags regarding to it. How can I do that? Do you know a class for that? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is really not precise. Do you have examples of what you want to do? And, more importantly, what have **you** tried?

Comment: I have not seen an example, so I am asking it if anyone have! I am stacked at possibility and the way of making it. Isn't that an enough reason? Please keep you polemics for somewhere else, this not the right place!

Comment: take a look at this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039238/how-to-auto-tag-content-algorithms-and-suggestions-needed

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? "Creating tags" can mean a dozen different things.

Comment: Hey Pekka. It s nice to see you! @HamZa DzCyberDeV 's answer helped me. I will be glad if you have any more suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How good do you need the tags to be?

You could simply **count n-gram word frequencies**.
With some tweaking this can create perfectly valid tags to use with blog posts, for example.

If you're looking for something more advanced, and you have a corpus of documents, you could use **TF*IDF** (Term frequency, Inverse Document Frequency). This will show meaningful keywords mentioned in 1 document, based on their improbability of appearing in other documents. It will give you good results providing your corpus is large enough.

A shortcut approach might be to **identify a relevant section** of the content (title? category? source?) and use something like this instead.

Also [**Yahoo has a term extraction API**](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V1/termExtraction.html) which you might find interesting.