# Tag auto discovery from text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, elasticsearch, nlp

I have an application where I store Articles from users. I want to provide a way to auto-categorize and/or auto-tag the body of articles automatically when it are created.
For example:

Let's say I have an article with this content:

> "They refuse to permit us to obtain the refuse permit"

At the time the user creates this article I want to auto determine and save into the database the tag(s) discovered that is *refuse permit* (it contains the most important words on the text; "Most important" word set on phases is what I want to find how to implement)

I'm looking for a solution where I can auto-tag/auto-categorize text from articles as in the example if possible using just ruby libraries.
My question is: what tool or algorithm (ruby or not) I can use to solve the problem in an efficient way?

Comment: Firstly I have reformulated the question and second, I think SO is a good place for asking this kind of stuff, I have done a previous research about the topic and there are a lot of solutions, I'm looking here somebody who points me in the right direction here. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Ok, maybe it will help if you asked more clearly as said here.http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html `When you ask your question, display the fact that you have done these things first; this will help establish that you're not being a lazy sponge and wasting people's time. Better yet, display what you have learned from doing these things. We like answering questions for people who have demonstrated they can learn from the answers.`

Comment: you want to auto-tag articles? What kind of tags if you may specify? Also are these tags random or specifically assigned for specific/individual articles?

Comment: @shivam I want to find relevant words on articles and mark them as tags, it will be a random and "infinite" set

Comment: @CarlosCastellanos Sorry but its still not clear. what is your question? Your SO ques motive is to find the tag or to assign the tag? Cause assigning can be done easily while saving. If you want help in finding the tag, you need to specify more conditions and basis on which you want to create/assign tags

Comment: @shivam I have updated my question, I want to find the text from existing text, hope it clarifies.

Comment: @Carlos, are you looking for something similar to this: http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/features/concept-tagging/ . Generating tags based on content/text is a open NLP problem (research problem). Also found a question on SO that looked similar to your question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6039492/689625